# Regex going crazy with space to comma conversion

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm simulating input with tags in it made from span, just like you can see here when you type tags in StackOverflow question.

HTML:

```
<div id="tags" contenteditable></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var t = $("#tags")

t.keyup(function (e) {

    t.html(t.html().replace(/([\w]+) /gi, '$1, ').replace(/([\w]+),/gi, '<span class=tag>$1<a href="#">x</a></span>&nbsp'));

    range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
    range.selectNodeContents(t[0]); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
    range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
    selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
    selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
    selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
    $("span a").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove()
    })
});
```

It should convert text followed by comma with `<span></span>` and convert any text followed by space to text followed by comma. the same you can see here in stack overflow.

It works for first tag but when I start typing the second one a mess ensures. to make it clear.. I begin by typing "php,"(or "php ") and it converts nicely to a tag (span). When I start typing "j" ("javascript") this is the mess that it creates:

[image: messy screengrab]

and I cannot understand what's wrong with the regex.

```
t.html(t.html().replace(/([\w]+) /gi, '$1, ').replace(/([\w]+),/gi, '<span class=tag>$1<a href="#">x</a></span>&nbsp'));
```

Shouldn't it work nicely? What am I doing wrong?

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5hwr4q9/)

Comment: You miss the fact that the regex will be applied to the whole `t` contents - including the `<span>` you've injected.

Comment: @raina77ow that's crazy. what other option i have other than html to select content inside contenteditable div and void selecting <span> too?

Comment: tried replacing `t.html(t.html().replace(/([\w]+) /gi, '$1, ').replace(/([\w]+),/gi, '<span class=tag>$1<a href="#">x</a></span>&nbsp'));` with `t.html(t.html().replace(/(?!<span class=tag>) /gi, '$1, ').replace(/([\w]+),/gi, '<span class=tag>$1<a href="#">x</a></span>&nbsp'));` but its worse..

Comment: this regex isnt working either.. `t.html(t.html().replace(/[^<span class="tag">][\w]+[^<a href="#">x</a></span>]/gi, '$1, ').replace(/([\w]+),/gi, '<span class=tag>$1<a href="#">x</a></span>&nbsp'));`

Comment: how do you even select just the text? is it really so difficult?

Comment: even checked on http://regex101.com/#javascript and it seems correct

Comment: Ignore any spans already there and just act on the text input from right now. You are currently wrapping all previous `span`s (and their attributes and so on) into other spans. On the next typing, all of THOSE spans are wrapped in more spans. So, therefore, don't act on them.

Comment: @Vld thanks.. I got how stupid this regex was. going to try executing regex after cursor position